# Java Hibernate MySQL долго обновляет 30т. строк, как ускорить

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

MySQL, нужно обновить в таблице 30 000 строк, сейчас это занимает примерно 30 минут, а это очень долго.

Вот код

```
public <T> void update(List<T> updateDBList) {
    for (T el : updateDBList) {
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.merge(el);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
    }
}
```

Как мне ускорить этот процесс??? 30 000 строк это очень мало возможно скоро их будет 1млн.

Comment: Неужели ждали 30 минут?) Вы на каждый элемент открываете транзакцию, обновляете, коммитите. Почитайте про batch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблему решил следующим способом:
1. В файл persistence.xml добавил строчку

```
<property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size" value="50"/>
```

2. Метод сделал так

public  void update(List updateDBList) {

```
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        for (int i = 0; i < updateDBList.size(); i++) {
            em.merge(updateDBList.get(i));
            if (i % 50 == 0) {
                em.flush();
                em.clear();
            }
        }
        em.getTransaction().commit();
    }
```

После этих манипуляций скорость увеличилась раз в 10-20